# Search for all substings between "+" and "n" characters

Tags: c++, substring

I'm trying to change some equations from input file to a "readable" form.
Currently I need to read all numerical values (as substrings, will convert them to int later) within a string P. All the values I'm interested with are between "+" and "n" characters (in this order for one loop, and the inverted order for other loop).
I need a loop which finds all of them and save them to array (of unknown size, since I don't know how long the string P will be).

Input examples (strings P in quotes):

1. > "+n2+-n"
   >   First loop (reads from + to n) so substrings C are: "", "-"
   >   The second loop (reads from n to +) so substrings E are: "2", ""
2. > "+2n3+3n2+n"
   >   First loop: "2", "3", ""
   >   Second loop: "3", "2", ""
3. > "+-n14+-11n+1"
   >   First loop: "-", "-11"
   >   Second loop: "14", ""

I could add "+" to the end of the P string if solution requires.

ps. If someone's have an idea how to extract a constant from the end of string seen in example 3 (+1, or any other) I would really appreciate. The hard thing is I cannot tell how long it'll be (can by +1 can be -300000 or so).

Comment: The `Split` method of the `RegExp` class may help.

Comment: Sort of. The whole mess is caused by human natural language used in input file. Unfortunately I cannot do anything about the format of it. Also I'm forced to use standard libraries (no Boost etc).

Answer (score 2):

Please consider to take a look at regular expressions (in general) and the new std::regex class from c++0x (in particular).

[C++0x: Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Regular_expressions)

Regular expressions are always a elegant solution if you want to parse any more complex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood your question, but what I personally use whenever i have unknown-length / extremely big inputs is a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) , that you could implement in C++ with [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) , which is also possible in C with malloc(), if you ever find that you need C syntax.

As with the parsing of the input, you can use a variable initialized with 1, and you just multiply it with -1 every time you get to the end of a substring, and use simple if statement that covers each case. Or you could use a char that takes either "n" or "+", and so you have to make the if statement cover only a few lines of code, after you're done with the actual parsing, and whenever your cursor gets to the above-mentioned char variable, it acts like it's done it's job for another substring.